# T-SQL query FOR XML output, how to correctly format XML query to specification

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, formatting

Hi and thank you for your time in advance. I am fairly new to formating XML output from a SQL query, so here it goes :) I need to format my FOR XML SQL query (in SSMS 2012) to match this format:

```
<HR_Data>
    <ClientInfo>
      <OrganizationOID>XXXX</OrganizationOID>
      <ClientId>XXXX</ClientId>
    </ClientInfo>
    <EmployeeHRData>
      <Employee_ID>XXXX</Employee_ID>
      <SocialSecurityNumber>XXXX</SocialSecurityNumber>
      ....
    </EmployeeHRData>
    <EmployeeHRData>
      <Employee_ID>XXXX</Employee_ID>
      <SocialSecurityNumber>XXXX</SocialSecurityNumber>
      ....
    </EmployeeHRData>
</HRData>
```

So in words, a ClientInfo header with info specific to the company, and then an EmployeeHRData section that repeats for each employee, all wrapped in a HRData tag.

So far, I have the following output(Client info repeats, instead of appearing only once, and have a FinalOutputTable tag that doesn't belong):

```
<HR_Data>
  <FinalOutputTable>
    <ClientInfo>
      <OrganizationOID>XXXX</OrganizationOID>
      <ClientId>XXXX</ClientId>
    </ClientInfo>
    <EmployeeHRData>
      <Employee_ID>XXXX</Employee_ID>
      <SocialSecurityNumber>XXXX</SocialSecurityNumber>
      ....
    </EmployeeHRData>
  </FinalOutputTable>
  <FinalOutputTable>
    <ClientInfo>
      <OrganizationOID>XXXX</OrganizationOID>
      <ClientId>XXXX</ClientId>
    </ClientInfo>
    <EmployeeHRData>
      <OrganizationOID>XXXX</OrganizationOID>
      <ClientId>XXXX</ClientId>
      ....
    </EmployeeHRData>
  </FinalOutputTable>
</HRData>
```

Which is generated from:

```
SELECT (SELECT 'XXXX' AS 'OrganizationOID', 'XXXX' AS 'ClientId'
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) ClientInfo

        ,(SELECT [AOID] AS AssociateOID
                ,ISNULL([Employee Identifier], '') AS Employee_ID
                ,ISNULL(SSN, '') AS SocialSecurityNumber
                ,.........

        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) EmployeeHRData            


INTO #FinalOutputTable
FROM XXXX
WHERE XXXX
ORDER BY XXXX

SELECT * FROM #FinalOutputTable AS FinalOutputTable
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('HR_Data'), ELEMENTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a nested ClientId element inside the ClientInfo element you use

```
Select 11 as "ClientInfo/ClientId"
```

So you can use the forward slash to define the location for the value in the xml result.

EDIT: you can use the code below if you want to return a document for one client.

```
Declare @HR_Data xml
Set @HR_Data=
(Select HR_Data.ClientInfo
 from
(
Select  (
     SELECT 'XXXX' AS 'OrganizationOID', 'XXXX' AS 'ClientId'
     FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ) ClientInfo
) HR_Data 
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('HR_Data'))


Declare @EmployeeHRData xml
Set @EmployeeHRData=
(SELECT   
      [AOID] AS AssociateOID
      ,ISNULL([Employee Identifier], '') AS Employee_ID
      ,ISNULL(SSN, '') AS SocialSecurityNumber
       ,.........
       from table_name
   FOR XML PATH('EmployeeHRData'), TYPE
   )


SET @HR_Data.modify(
    'insert sql:variable("@EmployeeHRData")
    as last into (/HR_Data[1])')
Select @HR_Data
```

Comment: I am confused. The ClientID is currently nested inside the Client Info element. Currently the ClientInfo tag is repeated for each employee, and I need the ClientInfo element to only appear once at the very top.

Comment: I got what your are asking for now. I have updated the answer.